# Selenium - Modal dialog present - how to accept information?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog, nunit

I have a following problem. After Submit some date on page I have a modal dialog like on the picture:

[image]

I want to click "ENTER" to go through that modal but it does not work.
I have following code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.submit")).Click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

After click on continue manually test go back to next page. I must go through this modal to continue the test. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution by following code:

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

It works for me.

Comment: This is fantastic and worked like a charm for me!  I upvoted this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In java:

```
Alert alert = m_driver.switchTo().alert(); 
alert.accept();
```

Comment: @Piyush Sorry, missed that.
I got here while searching it for java, Probably sometime someone else will land here as well :) wont hurts anyone.