# .exe starts successfully with windows scheduler but not throws error on visualcron

Tags: windows, cron, scheduler

Scripts works fine when I run the exe when I am logged into the machine. But when I schedule the .exe on VisualCron, it throws an exception. I tried the same .exe on windows scheduler, I am able to run the job.

Error details given below. How do I work around this issue. Please help.

Code:

```
using log4net;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace SeleniumDocManager
{

    class To_Run_IE
    {
        private static ILog log;
          static void ConfigureLog4Net()
        {
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["applicationname"] = "Selenium";
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType());
        }

        static string CreateFileFolder()
        {
            //Environment.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\myCSharp\\mySelenium";
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = "E:\\Jobs\\Visualcron\\QA\\myInfoCenter";
            string foldername = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            if (!Directory.Exists(foldername))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(foldername);
            }
            return foldername;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureLog4Net();
            string todayFolder = CreateFileFolder();
            string programOutputPath = Path.Combine(todayFolder, "ProgramOutput.txt");
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(programOutputPath, true))
            {
                file.WriteLine("Starting Test, page title is: " + driver.Title);
            }
            string outputpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                Console.Write ("outputpath is :" + outputpath + "        ");
            log.Debug("Starting Test, page title is: " + driver.Title);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Starting Test, page title is: " + driver.Title);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Page source is: " + driver.PageSource);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://cf-qa-web01:100/Home/Attachments/B1C56889-54D6-E211-ACC3-0050569D4561");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            By byXpath = By.XPath("//select[@id='DocumentType']");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byXpath));
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(byXpath);
            var selectElement = new SelectElement(element);
            int options = selectElement.Options.Count;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Screenshot s0 = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            s0.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(todayFolder, string.Format("{0}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.jpeg", "Document_Manager_Initial_Screenshot", DateTime.Now)),
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            try
            {            
                Console.WriteLine(selectElement.Options[0].Text);
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(programOutputPath, true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine("Capture @ " + selectElement.Options[0].Text);
                }

                string _getssName = selectElement.Options[0].Text;
                //new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(byXpath)).SelectByIndex(0);
                Console.WriteLine("Capturing " + "Select Document Type" + " dropdown screenshot");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Screenshot sss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                sss.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(todayFolder, string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.jpeg", " Select Document Type ", "dropdown", DateTime.Now))
```

Error Details:

Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot() at SeleniumDocManager.To_Run_IE.Main(String[] args) Exception in Task: Non zero exit code

Comment: The error says there is some sort of dialog being thrown and it doesn't like it. Check the solution here though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991089/selenium-modal-dialog-present-how-to-accept-information

Answer (score 0):

By default, all Tasks are executed in the background by the VisualCron service, normally running as SYSTEM account. If, for some reason, your executable tries to show an interface it will block the system as there is no desktop in the background to display or interact with the message.

You might want to know the reason why it throws the error. But if it works outside of VisualCron the cause is normally that you are not;

1. using a Credential
2. "Load profile" has not been checked in the Credential settings